# При парсинге многостраничного сайта, выдаёт ошибку: StaleElementReferenceException, как быть?

Tags: python, selenium

При парсинге многостраничного сайта, выдаёт ошибку: StaleElementReferenceException, как быть?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
import time

print("ENTER MAIL: ")
mail = input()
print("ENTER PASSWORD: ")
pas = input()


driver= webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.udemy.com')
print("GOT URL\n")
time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-purpose='header-login']").click()
print("OPEN LOGIN FORM\n")
time.sleep(5)

webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(570, 295).click().send_keys(mail).perform()
time.sleep(5)
print("PRINT MAIL\n")

webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(100, 65).click().send_keys(pas).perform()
time.sleep(5)
print("PRINT PASSWORD\n")

webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(0, 60).click().perform()
time.sleep(5)
print("AUTORIZATION\n")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data-purpose='my-courses']").click()
time.sleep(6)
print("GO TO URL\n")

#strongs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//strong[@class = 'details__name']")

f = open('udemy_titles','w', encoding='utf8')
f.write("USERNAME: ")
f.write(mail + "\n")
f.write("PASSWORD: ")
f.write(pas + "\n")
f.write("TOTAL COURSES: ")

try:
    div  = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='pager-label']").text
    div_1 = div.split(" ")[-2]
    f.write(div_1 + "\n")
    hrf = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='pagination pagination-expanded']/li[7]").text
    y = 0
    while int(hrf) > y:
        # strongs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//strong[@class = 'details__name']")
        # time.sleep(1)
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        strongs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//strong[@class = 'details__name']")
        for strong in strongs:
            print(strong.text)
            y += 1
            f.write("COURSE " + "#")
            f.write(str(y) + ": ")
            f.write(strong.text + "\n")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class = 'pagination-next udi udi-next']").click()
        time.sleep(5)
        #driver.get('https://www.udemy.com/home/my-courses/learning/?p=8')

except:
    print("ONE PAGE\n")

selem = 0
for strong in strongs:
    print(strong.text)
    selem += 1
    f.write("COURSE " + "#")
    f.write(str(selem) + ": ")
    f.write(strong.text + "\n")

f.close()

driver.close()
time.sleep(2)
```

[image: Вот и сам сайт]

Скрипт работает до 8 страницы, дальше выбивает ошибку, идей уже нет никаких.

Comment: Во первых, не используйте time.sleep, используйте вместо него webdriverwait

Comment: Без логина и пароля не могу ваш код проверить

Comment: macparag@hotmail.com  :   mileage00

Comment: так у вас ошибка в строке print(strong.text).

Comment: Спасибо за код, вроде работает. Но ошибки вроде как в “print(strong.text)” нет. ( По крайней мере у меня )

Comment: Traceback тогда скиньте

Comment: Это уже не важно, единсвенное очень туплю по поводу того, как сделать нормальную номерацию кол-ва курсов

Comment: + скрипт иногда пропускает почему то страницы

Answer (score 0):

Я обычно прохожу по Url.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

def parse_pagination(driver):
    #Находим элемент Ul у pagination
    ul_pagination = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul.pagination.pagination-expanded")
    #Находим li элементы, берем предпоследний элемент
    li_pagination = ul_pagination.find_elements_by_css_selector("li")[-2]
    #Определяем количество страниц
    count_page = int(li_pagination.find_element_by_css_selector("a").text)
    #Здесь будят хранятся ссылки
    urls = []
    for i in range(2, count_page + 1):
        urls.append("https://www.udemy.com/home/my-courses/learning/?p=" + str(i))
    return urls

def parse_list(driver):
    #Набор карточек, ожидаем появления
    div_card_wrapper = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.card-wrapper")))
    # Карточки
    div_cards = div_card_wrapper.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.card.card--learning")
    for div_card in div_cards:
        #Ссылка
        a = div_card.find_element_by_css_selector("a.card--learning__details > div > strong")
        name = a.text
        print(name)


print("ENTER MAIL: ")
mail = ""
print("ENTER PASSWORD: ")
pas = ""


driver= webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.udemy.com')
print("GOT URL\n")
time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-purpose='header-login']").click()
print("OPEN LOGIN FORM\n")
time.sleep(5)

webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(570, 295).click().send_keys(mail).perform()
time.sleep(5)
print("PRINT MAIL\n")

webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(100, 65).click().send_keys(pas).perform()
time.sleep(5)
print("PRINT PASSWORD\n")

webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(0, 60).click().perform()
time.sleep(5)
print("AUTORIZATION\n")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data-purpose='my-courses']").click()
time.sleep(6)
print("GO TO URL\n")

#strongs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//strong[@class = 'details__name']")

f = open('udemy_titles','w', encoding='utf8')
f.write("USERNAME: ")
f.write(mail + "\n")
f.write("PASSWORD: ")
f.write(pas + "\n")
f.write("TOTAL COURSES: ")


parse_list(driver)
urls = parse_pagination(driver)
for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    parse_list(driver)

driver.close()
time.sleep(2)
```

Остальное добавите сами, что я удалил. И при возможности, используйте Webdriver, это позволит увеличить скорость парсинга